# Kubernetes and Dask and Scheduler

Tags: python, kubernetes, dask

My code looks something like this

```py
def myfunc(param):
    # expensive stuff that takes 2-3h

mylist = [...]
client = Client(...)
mgr = DeploymentMgr()
# ... setup stateful set ...
futures = client.map(myfunc, mylist, ..., resources={mgr.hash.upper(): 1})
client.gather(futures)
```

I have dask running on a Kubernetes cluster. At the start of the program I create a stateful set. This is done via `kubernetes.client.AppsV1Api()`. Then I wait for up to 30 minutes until all workers that I have requested are available. For this example, say I request 10 workers, but after 30 minutes, only 7 workers are available. Finally, I call `client.map()` and pass a function and a list to it. This list has 10 elements. However, dask will only use 7 workers to process this list! Even if after a couple of minutes the remaining 3 workers are available, dask does not assign any list elements to them even if none of the processing of the first elements has finished.

How can I change that behaviour of dask? Is there a a way of telling dask (or the scheduler of dask) to periodically check for newly arriving workers and distribute work more "correctly"? Or can I manually influence the distribution of these list elements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dask will balance loads once it has a better understanding of how long the tasks will take.  You can give an estimate of task length with the configuration values

```yaml
distributed:
  scheduler:
    default-task-durations:
      myfunc: 1hr
```

Or, once Dask finishes one of these tasks, it will know how to make decisions around that task in the future.

I believe that this has also come up a couple of times on the GitHub issue tracker.  You may want to search through https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried setting the default task durations, but I havn't tested it yet. Before I did that, I replaced the single client.map() call with several client.submit() calls. Then I asked the scheduler to give me all the IP addresses of all the "running" workers and then used these IP addresses in the `workers` argument of client.submit(). However, this did not solve the problem. So I am hoping that the default-task-duration will solve it.